# Exit Python Discord Bot script to command line

Tags: command, discord, bots, line, exit

I have a working Discord BOT that I would like to quit and exit back to the Windows command prompt upon Control-C. I have tried the various suggestions found here but none work for me. I do hit the sys._exit() call but it does not terminate the script - or if it does, then it doesn't go back to the command prompt anyway. Here is the condensed down code, I expect it is something to do with kicking off the t1 thread?

```
myEvent = Event()
myEventStatus = STOPPED
client = None
   

# Mainline starts here
def main(e):

    while myEventStatus != QUIT:
        e.wait()
        e.clear()
        # do_something()

    #await client.close()
    sys._exit()


def handleExit(signal, frame):
    #global original_sigint
    #signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint)
    global myEventStatus
    myEventStatus = QUIT
    myEvent.set()

# Startup Information
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))
    t1 = threading.Thread(name='blocking', target=main, args=(myEvent,))
    t1.start()


original_sigint = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handleExit)

# Create bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

thanks